# How to Bulk Insert csv with double quotes around all values?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, csv, bulkinsert

I am trying to insert a .csv file into SQL Server 2008 R2.

The .csv is 300+MB from http://ipinfodb.com/ip_database.php Complete
(City), 4.0M records.

Here're the top 5 lines, with 1st line = column headers:

```
"ip_start";"country_code";"country_name";"region_code";"region_name";"city";"zipcode";"latitude";"longitude";"metrocode"
"0";"RD";"Reserved";;;;;"0";"0";
"16777216";"AU";"Australia";;;;;"-27";"133";
"17367040";"MY";"Malaysia";;;;;"2.5";"112.5";
"17435136";"AU";"Australia";;;;;"-27";"133";
```

I tried Import and Export Data, and BULK INSERT, but haven't been able to import them correctly yet.

Shall I resort to use bcp? can it handle stripping the `""`? how?

Thank you very much.

Comment: ...or you could use a regex replace to strip out the double quotes...

Comment: file too large, will take forever to strip out

Comment: If you want to go that route, you could open it in a real text editor like Textpad or Ultraedit and perform a find/replace on quotation marks replacing them with an empty string.  I've worked with 180MB files using those utilities and it was painless - you might give it a shot.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Got it, forgot to set **Text Qualifier** as `"`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your data looks pretty inconsistent since NULL values don't also carry a quotation enclosure.

I believe you can create a format file to customize to your particular csv file and its particular terminators in SQL SERVER.

See more here:
http://lanestechblog.blogspot.com/2008/08/sql-server-bulk-insert-using-format.html

Answer (score 0):

Is this a single import or are you wanting to schedule a recurring import?  If this is a one-time task, you should be able to use the Import and Export Wizard.  The text qualifier will be the quotation mark ("), be sure to select *column names in the first data row*, and you'll want to convey that the field delimiter is the semicolon (;).

I'm not certain the file is properly formatted - the last semicolon following each of the data rows might be a problem.  If you hit any errors, simply add a new column header to the file.

EDIT: I just did a quick test, the semicolons at the end will be treated as part of the final value in that row.  I would suggest adding a ;"tempheader" at the end of your header (first) row - that will cause SQL to treat the final semicolon as a delimiter and you can delete that extra column once the import is complete.

Comment: I will try Import and Export Wizard again tomorrow, but it kept on crashing earlier today.

Answer (score 0):

In C# you can use this code, working for me

```
 public bool CSVFileRead(string fullPathWithFileName, string fileNameModified, string tableName)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["dbConnectionString"]);
        string filepath = fullPathWithFileName;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filepath);
        string line = sr.ReadLine();
        string[] value = line.Split(',');
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow row;
        foreach (string dc in value)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(dc));
        }
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            //string[] stud = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            //for (int i = 0; i < stud.Length; i++)
            //{
            //    stud[i] = stud[i].Replace("\"", "");
            //}
            //value = stud;
            value = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            if (value.Length == dt.Columns.Count)
            {
                row = dt.NewRow();
                row.ItemArray = value;
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
        SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(con.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
        bc.DestinationTableName = tableName;
        bc.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
        con.Open();
        bc.WriteToServer(dt);
        bc.Close();
        con.Close();

        return true;
    }
```